# how to make text align right in labels inside row

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to make simple demo as given in image ![enter image description here][1]

I am able to display contend in view .But I am facing few issue in making this page

- how to add background image in contend .I don't have same background image but I have similar background image in this url
- how to make text align left in application  .The end character in a sigle line .how to make all label left align.
- how to add separator line in grid view .Actually In all row separator are present.

here is my code

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>Tabs Example</title>

  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

    <ion-view>
        <ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-balanced">
            <div class="buttons" style="font-size:20px ;padding:3px">
              <i style="font-size:30px;" class='icon ion-chevron-left'></i>
            </div>
            <h1 class="title">Account</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content>
            <div class="button-bar">
                <a class="button button-small" ui-sref="a" ui-sref-active="button-balanced">Account Details</a>
                <a class="button button-small" ui-sref="l" ui-sref-active="button-balanced">Related</a>
                <a class="button button-small" ui-sref="dinner" ui-sref-active="button-balanced">d</a>
                <a class="button button-small" ui-sref="dinner" ui-sref-active="button-balanced">Notes</a>
            </div>
               <div>
                <h4 class="headerTitle">Account Information</h4>
                <div class="row rowoffset">
                    <div class="col gey_label_font">Number:</div>
                    <div class="col">0981234165</div>
                    <div class="col"></div>
                    <div class="col gey_label_font">Name:</div>
                    <div class="col">Girish Padhve</div>
                </div>

                <div class="row rowoffset">
                    <div class="col gey_label_font">Owner:</div>
                    <div class="col">Girish</div>
                    <div class="col"></div>
                    <div class="col gey_label_font">Total AR:</div>
                    <div class="col">345</div>
                </div>

                <div class="row rowoffset">
                    <div class="col gey_label_font">Last:</div>
                    <div class="col">123</div>
                    <div class="col"></div>
                    <div class="col gey_label_font">Last ] Amount:</div>
                    <div class="col">9891234165</div>
                </div>

                <div class="row rowoffset">
                    <div class="col gey_label_font"> Net Collectible:</div>
                    <div class="col">123</div>
                    <div class="col"></div>
                    <div class="col gey_label_font">Past Due:</div>
                    <div class="col">9891234165</div>
                </div>

                <div class="row rowoffset">
                    <div class="col gey_label_font"> Total Past Due:</div>
                    <div class="col">123</div>
                    <div class="col"></div>
                    <div class="col gey_label_font">Total Promised:</div>
                    <div class="col">9891234165</div>
                </div>

                <div class="row rowoffset">
                    <div class="col gey_label_font">Total Disputed:</div>
                    <div class="col">123</div>
                    <div class="col"></div>
                    <div class="col gey_label_font">Limit:</div>
                    <div class="col">9891234165</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row rowoffset">
                    <div class="col gey_label_font">Remaining:</div>
                    <div class="col">123</div>
                    <div class="col gey_label_font"></div>
                    <div class="col">Credit Score:</div>
                    <div class="col">9891234165</div>
                </div>


            </div>

        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
    </html>
```

Comment: `class="pull-left"` should work(if bootstrap is there)..otherwise you need use `float: left`

Comment: Maybe try css property text-align on the parent container element of the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns in your codepen already look aligned left to me, so I assume you worked that out. As for the background image and the separator lines, you can use these css rules: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXNVvv

```
#wrapper {
   background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/nz1fzunlqzzz7uo/login_bg.png?dl=0);
}

.rowoffset{
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
}

.gey_label_font{
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: sorry I need aligned right ..please check below image ..Acount Number ,Account Name ,Account number is right align

Comment: alright, I edited my answer and the codepen. Does that work for you?